# vlc stream left and right audio channel from input separately

Tags: command-line, mono, encode, vlc, channel

I have stereo mp3 file as source.
On the left channel voice keeps repeating "left, left left"
On the right channel voice keeps repeating "right, right, right".

How can I stream left channel only from audio source mp3 using Vlc, in command line?
I would like to stream to web server on port 777 sound from the left channel in mp3.
I would like to stream to web server on port 778 sound from the right channel in mp3.

localhost:777 would keep saying  "left, left left"
localhost:778 would keep saying  "right, right, right".

tried this, did not work

```
vlc --sout=#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=mp3,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{mux=mp3,dst=:777/} :sout-keep lr.mp3 --loop --stereo-mode=3
```

also tried --sout-mono-channel=0, did not work.

Thanks.

using this in web browser: radio.html

```
<audio controls title=radio1 autoplay >
  <source src="http://localhost:777" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```

edit:
mp3 with different left and right channel is here: https://easyupload.io/oomi82

---

edit 2

Did not manage to do it using vlc, athough it has downmix, and remap filters, which do not work for me. Directx or windows media output.
Used ffmpeg to serve single channel to vlc.

Sending source audio using mpv to send audio through left and righ channel through audio cable. Front left (fl), and front right (fr):

```
mpv --priority=abovenormal --audio-device=wasapi/{xxx}  --audio-channels=fl sourcefile.mp3

mpv --priority=abovenormal --audio-device=wasapi/{xxx}  --audio-channels=fr sourcefile.mp3
```

On the destination pc, using ffmpeg to serve left and right audio channel separately to VLC:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="Microphone (Realtek High Definition Audio)" -af channelmap="0-0|0-1" -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 160k  -f rtp rtp://localhost:578

ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="Microphone (Realtek High Definition Audio)" -af channelmap="1-0|1-1" -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 160k  -f rtp rtp://localhost:579
```

and using vlc to serve as web server

vlc.exe --vlm-conf=stream3.vlm

stream3.vlm:

new radio2 broadcast enabled
setup radio2 input rtp://localhost:578
setup radio2 output #http{mux=mp3,dst=localhost:778/radio2}
setup radio2 option sout-keep
setup radio2 option live-caching=300
control radio2 play

new radio3 broadcast enabled
setup radio3 input rtp://localhost:579
setup radio3 output #http{mux=mp3,dst=localhost:779/radio3}
setup radio3 option sout-keep
setup radio3 option live-caching=300
control radio3 play